# Can I connect to surveillance camera remotely without direct access?

Tags: surveillance-cameras, ip-address

For using ip camera you need to use app on your phone. When you setup camera you connect to it on your phone. But if you need to give somebody access to this camera, can you import settings from already connected phone and send them to other peson (in other city), so he can connect to this camera.

Or maybe I can connect using ip address? But how I can get it?

Probably it depends on the type of camera, what about [EZVIZ C6CN 1080p Indoor Pan/Tilt Wi-Fi Security Camera](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/ezviz-c6cn-1080p-indoor-pan-tilt-wi-fi-security-camera/1001514143)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically how the security camera setups work is, each vendor has their own app or web site where you can access your video stream. So once you have access to this app or website, you can share the credentials with any one and they can view the stream on the same app or website on they devices. So all you need is the authentication credentials to get access to view the stream.